# I can't reall understan why my code loops when i refactor it to use useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so my code was originally written using just props but then my teacher asked me to remove those props and use useContext instead. Eveything was fine until i try to load the code. It just loops and bugs my browser. Could you guys gimme a clue on what it might be?

PAGE:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { PageNav } from "./styles";
import { UserContext } from "../../contextandprovider/context";

const schema = yup
  .object({
    password: yup.string().required("este campo não pode ficar vazio"),
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email("Precisa ser um email válido")
      .required("Este campo não pode ficar vazio"),
  })
  .required();

export function HomePage() {
  const { manageFormData, navigate } = useContext(UserContext);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });

  return (
    <PageNav>
      <span>Kenzie Hub</span>
      <div className="loginCard">
        <span className="loginCard__title">Login</span>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(manageFormData)} action="submit">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            id="email"
            placeholder="Insira seu melhor email..."
            type="text"
            {...register("email")}
          />
          <p>{errors.email?.message}</p>
          <label htmlFor="password">Senha</label>
          <input
            id="password"
            placeholder="Insira uma senha"
            type="password"
            {...register("password")}
          />
          <p>{errors.password?.message}</p>
          <button type="submit" className="loginCard__confirmButton">
            Entrar
          </button>
        </form>
        <span className="loginCard__noAccount"></span>
        <Link to="/subscribe">
          <button className="loginCard__subscribeButton">Cadastre-se</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </PageNav>
  );
}
```

CONTEXT:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import { Api } from "../services/api";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext({});

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  async function manageFormData(data) {
    try {
      const loginData = await Api.post("/sessions", data);
      // console.log(loginData.data.user);
      toast.success("Login efetuado com sucesso", {
        position: "top-right",
      });
      localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(loginData.data.user));
      navigate("/userPage");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.message);
      toast.error(error.response.data.message, {
        position: "top-right",
      });
    }
  }

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ manageFormData, navigate }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

PROVIDER:

```
import React from "react";

export function FunctionProvider({ children }) {
  return <FunctionProvider>{children}</FunctionProvider>;
}
```

I tried to check on my console to see what was going on but it simply got stuck within the inifite loop

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? And what's this `FunctionProvider` that's calling itself?

Comment: If you're calling `<FunctionProvider>` in your final App code then it will be causing indefinite recursion while React builds the component tree. React does not generally report errors during the construction phase.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from onSubmit property of form

you need to use arrow function or callable function (not calling funtion inside it )

so simply change

```
onSubmit={handleSubmit(manageFormData)}
```

to

```
 onSubmit={()=>handleSubmit(manageFormData)}
```